# Harden against privilege escalation in Microservices

Tags: security, microservices, api-gateway, stateful, penetration-testing

Please consider the following scenario.

- The system has a set of business owners (i.e. users of the system)
- Each business owner is mapped to a set of customers
- The business owners login to the system in order to manage their customers.

The business owners will select a single customer first, and from there onward his *session is bound that selected customer*.

I have a set of microservices, each requires a `Customer-ID` for processing. i.e.

- Microservice A exposes `GET /resource-a/{customer-id}`
- Microservice B exposes `POST /resource-b/{customer-id}`
- etc.

The `Customer-Id` is considered to be a sensitive information - so that it is in encrypted form.

However it's still vulnerable to **privilege-escalation**. i.e. one business owner may mistakenly share the encrypted customer-id through bookmarks etc.

- I want to avoid server-side authorization of customer-id against business owner because it is known to be a slow operation and and 90% of the APIs will have to repeat this authorization process
- All the microservices are stateless, so that it's not possible to encrypt the `Customer-Id` with the session-id as the key (since no stateful microservices/ session)
- Also I don't think it's a good idea to do this authorization at the gateway since it's not intended to perform such business logic.

How can I prevent privilege escalation in this situation?

Comment: If you don't get useful answers here, you might want to try https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. Raised the question at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196086/harden-against-privilege-escalation-in-microservices